# Can Pyserial work with hid devices?

Tags: python, linux, hid, pyserial

I am trying to access a USB device which appears in `/dev/` as `hidraw4`.

I have the specification of the communication interface (based on RS232 serial port communication), but I cannot even got the connection with pyserial to work :

**Code:**

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/hidraw4')
```

**Error:**

```
serial.serialutil.SerialException: Could not configure port: (22, 'Invalid argument')
```

I do not really understand what is the difference between the `hidraw` and `tty` files that I can found in `/dev/`. Can Pyserial connect to such devices (and if not, is there a workaround) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of researches, it appears that **no**, it is impossible to get Pyserial work with hidraw devices. I can recommend the following two different ways to solve the problem :

- Use [Pyusb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyusb/)
- Write your own USB driver (kernel space) that handles the device, and write an API to communicate with the driver

Comment: Did you finally solve the problem using any of the above methods? If so, how?